# How to generate c# interface from a ms sql table

Tags: sql-server, interface, get, c#-2.0, set

I have a sql table, it has many coloumns.

For Instance;

The Table :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[_BundleFlowData](

    [IsCustomer] [bit] NULL,
    [CustomerClientNo] [bigint] NULL,
    [BranchCode] [bigint] NULL,
    [BranchName] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [CitizenshipNo] [bigint] NULL,
    ...
```

I want a program/a solution that generates interface for each column of the table;

```
    bool IsCustomer { get; set; }
    long CustomerClientNo { get; set; }
    long BranchCode { get; set; }
    string BranchName{ get; set; }
    long CitizenshipNo{ get; set; }
   ...
```

What is your advice for this case above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use T4 Templates to connect to the database and generate your interfaces.

T4 Templates: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx

Answer (score 1):

LINQ to SQL

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you want to generate it from sql files (like in an SSDT project) instead of waiting until your database code is deployed, you can use [SqlSharpener](https://github.com/aeslinger0/sqlsharpener) to parse the files and then use the meta-object hierarchy it creates in a T4 template.

Disclaimer - I'm the creator of [SqlSharpener](https://github.com/aeslinger0/sqlsharpener).